# Recommendations for a case to 3D print: Pi B+/Pi 2

Tags: case

I've looked on Thingiverse and didn't find a case to my liking, and that was after having to sift through all the original cases that were pretty cool.  I guess the case designers havent gotten Pi B+ or Pi 2's?

Here are the things I am looking for in a case:

- Fits the Pi B+ / Pi 2
- VESA mount options
- Screw mount options
- Thick, sturdy walls
- GPIO accessible from the top

Nice to haves:

- Cable support
- Cool design

I have not seen many examples of what I am looking for, but this is what I would consider a baseline for the older Pi generation:

[Raspberry PI Case with Mounting](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:43587)

I printed the base of this one, but it needs some mounting options:

[Raspberry Pi case (model B+)](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:559858)

I have a Printrbot LC that has a larger than normal print area, and I typically print in ABS.  I haven't printed in a while, but I used to use Slic3r and Pronterface.

Comment: Could I ask why you arent modelling your own case? Personally, searching for things rather than doing them is a bit lame.

Comment: I certainly would like to.  Is it that easy?  As far as I can tell, I don't think it's that easy.  I looked into some 3D modeling software and it's tutorials a while back and didn't get very far.  I can't recall the name.  Open something or other.  It's just like with being a n00b on Linux: 3 seconds of work takes 3 hours of searching for commands and history because it's complicated and not explained so a n00b can understand it.

Comment: But making something by your own is the most funny part of 3d printing, rather than searching for things you need ^^ You may want to look at the video series "layer by layer" from adafruit or [take a look at the 3d printing page in their learning system](https://learn.adafruit.com/category/3d-printing). [Here is a tutorial for the raspberry pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/3d-printed-raspberry-pi-b-plus-enclosure/customization) . You really need to look at the part designs and how far their mounting holes are or how big they are etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pi 2 case that meets all your requirements...

http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:922740